# tensorflow map_fn on signle value Tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

### Is it possible to run map_fn on a tensor with a single value?

The following works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[3])
tf.map_fn(lambda x: x+1, a)
#output: [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

However this does not:

```
import tensorflow as tf
b = tf.constant(1.0)
tf.map_fn(lambda x: x+1, b)
#expected output: 2.0
```

- Is it possible at all?
- What am I doing wrong?

Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I see you accepted an answer, which correctly states that [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) is applying a function to elements of a tensor, and a scalar tensor has no elements. But it's not *impossible* to do this for a scalar tensor, you just have to [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) it before and after, like this code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
b = tf.constant(1.0)

if () == b.get_shape():
    c = tf.reshape( tf.map_fn(lambda x: x+1, tf.reshape( b, ( 1, ) ) ), () ) 
else:
    c = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x+1, b)
#expected output: 2.0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( c ) )
```

will output:

> 2.0

as desired.

This way you can factor this into an agnostic function that can take both scalar and non-scalar tensors as argument.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. As you probably saw it throws an error:

`ValueError: elems must be a 1+ dimensional Tensor, not a scalar`

The point of `map_fn` is to apply a function to each element of a tensor, so it makes no sense to use this for a scalar (single-element) tensor.

As to "what you are doing wrong": This is difficult to say without knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you!

I am using map_fn within a function that takes a tensor as argument that might/might not have size>1.

The second question was only in case it was possible and I was calling it incorrectly.

I will find a workaround :)

Comment: Ok, in that case the second answer should provide the desired workaround!